# Facebook connect with iPhone not working

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have set up two apps with Facebook Connect. The settings were exactly the same except from the App IDs, Bundle IDs, and on my app side, the Facebook Secret keys are different. The first app works perfectly. The second app doesn't.

The error I kept getting is that "Sorry, the application you're using is misconfigured..." I tried to delete the second app on FB and set up new ones and it still doesn't work. For proof of no error in my code, I enter the App ID and Secret of the first app to the second one, and it actually runs.

So does anyone know why? Is it because I could only have at any given point and time, one active Facebook app for one Facebook account? (Which is ridiculous.)

To add, I am simply using ShareKit. There's no magic in what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed your Facebook URL scheme in your target configuration?
It look like you haven't declared it.